# convert String to DateTime

Tags: ruby, date, time, parsing

I need to parse following String into a DateTime Object:
`30/Nov/2009:16:29:30 +0100`

Is there an easy way to do this?

*PS:* I want to convert the string above as is. The colon after the year is not a typo. I also want to solve the problem with Ruby and not RoR.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

[DateTime.strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-_strptime) allows you to specify the format and convert a String to a DateTime.

Comment: thanks. Missed, that I could give it my own format. Here's the working one: '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S'

Comment: @SkaveRat Does your string respect the timezone? I use `%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %Z`

Comment: For a list of available format abbreviations  https://gist.github.com/halloffame/5350249

Comment: It would be polite to specify example of conversion of string, which user asked, not only "go read there" (where's tons of information by the way). Stackoverflow popular not because it gives links to external documentation, but gives answers to questions

Comment: Is there any way to do "exact match"? Currently the behavior is "matching from beginning", so `%Y` will match both `2015` (as expected) and `2016-foo-bar` since it stops when it sees `2016`. This behavior is consistent with the C counterpart; however, the C function [returns the position of the end of matching](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html#tag_16_582_04) (e.g. the first `-` in the "2016" case) for us to decide whether the match is exact; in Ruby it returns a `DateTime`, so we can't tell whether there is still anything afterwards.

Answer (score 130):

Shouldn't this also work **for Rails**?

```
"30/Nov/2009 16:29:30 +0100".to_datetime
```

Comment: It continues to for me on mri ruby 1.9.2, probably should have mentioned that when I posted the snippet.

Comment: works nicely in Rails 3.2.3 using Ruby 1.9.3 ... "2012-05-16 02:30 UTC".to_datetime
 => Wed, 16 May 2012 02:30:00 +0000

Comment: This is also a Ruby on Rails method, not a Ruby method.

Comment: This should be:

`require 'active_support/all'`

and then

`"30/Nov/2009 16:29:30 +0100".to_datetime`

(you don't actually need all active_support extensions, but good luck figuring out which ones to require selectively)

Comment: ActiveSupport is laid out pretty sanely, but for the least amount of impact, this should be all you need to get `to_datetime` added to `String` objects: `require 'active_support/core_ext/string/conversions'`

Comment: The question is about "30/Nov/2009:16:29:30 +0100" and not "30/Nov/2009 16:29:30 +0100". That's another reason why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 55):

I have had success with:

```
require 'time'
t = Time.parse(some_string)
```

Answer (score 26):

This will convert the string in date to datetime, if using **Rails**:

```
"05/05/2012".to_time
```

Doc Reference: https://apidock.com/rails/String/to_time

Comment: This is a Ruby on Rails method, not a Ruby method.

Comment: Although this was not the answer to this question, it helped me a bunch. Thanks @user1425976

Comment: Why do people post Rails stuff on Ruby questions?

Answer (score 16):

convert string to date:

```
# without timezone
DateTime.strptime('2012-12-09 00:01:36', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
=> Sun, 09 Dec 2012 00:01:36 +0000

# with specified timezone
DateTime.strptime('2012-12-09 00:01:36 +8', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')
=> Sun, 09 Dec 2012 00:01:36 +0800
```

refer to:
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html

Comment: Why is this for Chinese Rails developers and not Rails developers from other countries?

Comment: Because I think U.S and other country people love 27/09/2021 this kind of date format. For Chinese, we only use the yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: I see -- thanks for clarifying, I figured it was something like that. I think other parts of the world use that format as well, which makes more sense to me. In USA we usually do 9/27/2021 which is about as strange as our units of measurement.

Answer (score 15):

I used `Time.parse("02/07/1988")`, like some of the other posters.

An interesting gotcha was that `Time` was loaded by default when I opened up IRB, but `Time.parse` was not defined. I had to `require 'time'` to get it to work.

That's with Ruby 2.2.

Answer (score 5):

in Ruby 1.8, the ParseDate module will convert this and many other date/time formats.  However, it does not deal gracefully with the colon between the year and the hour.  Assuming that colon is a typo and is actually a space, then:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

require 'parsedate'

s = "30/Nov/2009 16:29:30 +0100"
p Time.mktime(*ParseDate.parsedate(s))    # =>  Mon Nov 30 16:29:30 -0700 2009
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse a date time string with a given timezone as well:

```
zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
ActiveSupport::TimeZone[zone].parse("2020-05-24 18:45:00")
=> Sun, 24 May 2020 18:45:00 PDT -07:00
```