# Building a calendar navigation in Rails (controller and view links)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, parameters, controller

Trying to get the next month when clicking the `link_to`. I've done the following in the view.

**index.html.erb**

```
 <table class="rota">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <!-- Element will carry the month number for initializing this table correctly. -->
    <th class="month"-<%= @date_range.month %>">Days</th>
    <% @hospitals.each do |hsp| %>
        <th class="hospital-<%= hsp.shortname %>"><%= hsp.name %></th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @date_range.each do |d| %>
      <tr>
        <th><%= d.to_s(:short) %></th>
        <% @hospitals.each do |hsp| %>
            <td class="day-<%= d.to_s(:short) %> hospital-<%= hsp.shortname %>">&nbsp;</td> <!--Class on each td to make it identifiable -->
        <% end %>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= form_tag rota_days_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>
      <%= link_to 'Previous Month', rota_days_path(:beginning_of_month => @beginning_previous) %>
      <%= link_to 'Next Month', rota_days_path(:beginning_of_month => @beginning_next) %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

**Controller.rb**

```
  class RotaDaysController < ApplicationController
      # GET /rota_days
      # GET /rota_days.json
      # load_and_authorize_resource
      respond_to :json, :html
      def index
        @rota_days = RotaDay.all
        @hospitals = Hospital.all
        @t1 = Date.today.at_beginning_of_month
        @t2 = Date.today.end_of_month
        @dates = (@t1..@t2)  #Concat variable t1 + t2 together
        # @next_month = Date.today + 1.month(params[: ??? ] #Old

        if params[:next_month]
         # @next_month = Date.today >> 1
          @next_month = params[:next_month] + 1.month
          @t1 = @next_month.at_beginning_of_month
          @t2 = @next_month.end_of_month
          @dates = (@t1..@t2)
        end

        @title = "Rota"

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @rota_days }
        end
      end
```

I have identified that the reason why this may not be working is in because of the following in my controller `@next_month = params[:next_month] + 1.month` the last two called methods is defined only on time/date objects. but not on fixnum/string objects. I understand I am missing something from this

**Update**

I have found that the actual issue is that the `params[:next_month] is a string and I am trying to add a date to to it. Which means I need to convert the string to a date/time object.

**Console output:**

```
Started GET "/rota_days" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-14 22:14:36 +0000
Processing by RotaDaysController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  RotaDay Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `rota_days`.* FROM `rota_days` 
  Hospital Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `hospitals`.* FROM `hospitals` 
  Rendered rota_days/index.html.erb within layouts/application (23.0ms)
  Role Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `roles`.`id` = `roles_users`.`role_id` WHERE `roles_users`.`user_id` = 1 AND `roles`.`name` = 'Administrator' LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 42ms (Views: 39.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200825/convert-string-to-datetime

Comment: `Date.parse('string')` might also work, or calling `'string'.to_datetime` in Rails.

Comment: @ThomasKlemm so would that mean in my controller I could would have to replace `@next_month = params[:next_month] + 1.month` and do include `@next_month = Date.parse(':next_month') + 1.month`. Would this be correct?

Comment: I tried to do the following: `@next_month DateTime.strptime(params[:next_month], "%d/%m/%Y") + 1.month` But this did not seem to work for me. I also have updated the output of what I receive in the terminal

Comment: Do you care about calender months ('January', 'Februar') or do you consider your month to be a date range ('2012-01-01..2012-01-31')?

Comment: I do care about the calendar months. Basically I have a table that looks like the following image: http://i.imgur.com/2hF7X.png what initially is supposed to happen is that when you click the link_to 'Next month' you are redirected to the following months being Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.. However it is not doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken your code and refined it a bit to handle navigating between the months

```
class RotaDaysController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :html

  def index
    @title = "Rota"
    @rota_days = RotaDay.all
    @hospitals = Hospital.all

    # Find the beginning of the month we are currently displaying
    #   it can be either passed in through the params[:beginning_of_month]
    #   which is a string we parse into a date by calling '2013-01-01'.to_date
    #   By wrapping the .to_date call in .try(:to_date), the call will not throw
    #   a NoMethodError if no params[:beginning_of_month] is passed in and thus
    #   we would call nil.to_date => throws NoMethodError
    #
    #   If no parameter is passed in we want to display the current month
    @beginning_current = params[:beginning_of_month].try(:to_date) || Date.current.beginning_of_month

    # Let's build the date range of the month to display
    #   The nice thing about date / time ranges is that you can iterate over them
    #   in the view to create the calendar interface we are looking for
    @date_range = (@beginning_current.beginning_of_month..@beginning_current.end_of_month) 

    # Build references for previous and next month for navigation
    #   We can use the beginning of the previous and next month as a reference
    #   for which month to display.
    @beginning_next     = (@beginning_current + 1.month).beginning_of_month.to_s
    @beginning_previous = (@beginning_current - 1.month).beginning_of_month.to_s      

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @rota_days }
    end
  end
end
```

In the view you can use these strings in the link_to helpers.

```
<%= form_tag rota_days_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= link_to 'Previous Month', rota_days_path(:beginning_of_month => @beginning_previous) %>
    <%= link_to 'Next Month', rota_days_path(:beginning_of_month => @beginning_next) %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

You can also iterate over date ranges to display each date in the view

```
<% @date_range.each do |day| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

I hope this helps. Feel free to ask any questions you like, but it might take me 'till tomorrow to get back to you.

Comment: I forgot to paste my current index.html.erb. So I have updated the question.

Comment: I don't know if your code for creating the table works, but it looks fine.

Comment: The code for creating the table works fine. I also did try your suggested set up that you provided. But it appears to give me `NoMethodError in Rota_days#index` - undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass`. http://i.imgur.com/qGUO8.png. Also you mentioned that you I can iterate over date ranges to display each date in the view. I am assuming I would do this in the view. I have also updated my index.html.erb set up to include your suggested `<%= link_to %>`

Comment: You are calling `@dates.first` while I renamed the instance variable to `@date_range` if you used the code.

Comment: So I should effectively end up with `<th class="month"-<%= @date_range.month %>">Days</th>` also noticed under the start of the `<tbody>` I had `<% @dates.each do |d| %>` which I changed to `<% @date_range.each do |d| %>`. Updated the index.html.erb

Comment: I'm not sure whether `@date_range.month` will work, but you'll find out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21181/discussion-between-user532339-and-thomas-klemm)